# Displaying only records that don't have an update this month

Tags: mysql, sql

MySQL and PHP

I am attempting to write a SQL statement that will allow me to identify an individual that has not checked in this month.  I am stuck on how to write the code.

I have 2 tables

tbl_cust c
tbl_attend a

```
    SELECT
       c.custRFID,
       a.attendID,
       a.RFID,
       a.attendDate,
       a.attendStatus,
       a.attendStatusCode,
       a.attendNotes
    FROM
       tbl_cust c RIGHT OUTER JOIN tbl_attend a ON c.custRFID = a.RFID
    WHERE
       MONTH(a.attendDate) <> MONTH(CURDATE()) AND YEAR(a.attendDate) = 
       YEAR(CURDATE())
```

The code filters out this month, however, it returns every date prior to this month.  I only want to display the names from table c that don't have an entry in table a for this month. I don't need all the records.

```
-------------------------------------------------------------
ID    RFID          Date         Time   Status    Status Code
-------------------------------------------------------------
1     01 02 03 E1   2018-01-03   1835    1        1
2     02 02 04 E2   2018-01-06   1235    1        1
3     01 02 03 E1   2018-02-07   1801    1        1
4     02 02 04 E2   2018-02-11   1109    1        1
5     01 02 03 E1   2018-03-03   1835    1        1
6     02 02 04 E2   2018-03-06   1235    1        1
7     01 02 03 E1   2018-04-07   1801    1        1
8     02 02 04 E2   2018-04-11   1109    1        1
9     01 02 03 E1   2018-05-01   1032    1        1
```

If this was May 16, 2018 the following should be the output:

```
-----------------------------------------------------------
ID    RFID          Date         Time   Status    Status Code
-------------------------------------------------------------
8     02 02 04 E2   2018-04-11   1109    1        1
```

This is only using 2 customers, as the actual table will eventually have over 5,000 customers in it. with at least 1 entry per month. Some will have 3 of 4 entries per month, however, I only want to see those with no entry in the current calendar month.  I.e.... If they checked in anytime during the calendar month of May 2018, they should not be displayed on the output.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Can you include the expected output as well?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen ... Added more details. Thanks

Comment: my apologies, I have been out of pocket for the past few weeks... Family emergency. I will get back to this ASAP.  Thank you. for understanding.

Answer (score 1):

If you want someone who has ever checked in, then you can use aggregation:

```
select RFID
from attend a
group by RFID
having max(attendDate) < date_add(curdate(), interval 1 - day(curdate()) day);
```

Comment: Gordon, Thanks for the feedback, but we have them check in every month, and we need to be able to see only those that have not checked in this month.  I will read up on the SQL manual for the **group by and having** to see if this will get me where I need to be.

Comment: @WillD. . . . That is what this query does.

Comment: @Gordan Linoff.  The code works, however, it not filtering the way I intend it to work.  for instance, if a record is not for today it shows them on the list.  I am looking to filter results based on the current month.  I tried changing day to Month and it does not work correctly.

Comment: @WillD. . . . This should only be returning `RFID`s whose most recent record is *before* the current *month*, not day.  That is what the `date_add()` is doing -- getting the first day of the month.

Comment: @Gordan Linoff ... I understand, however it is returning all 100 plus entries in the table including entries made this month.

Comment: @WillD. . . . Are you sure you are using the `HAVING` clause correctly?  Is the data type of `AttendDate` really a date?

Comment: The `attendDate` is set as date in MySQL and also in the PHP code on the front end.  It stores as a default date type for MySQL.  What do you mean by using the `HAVING` clause correctly?

Comment: For instance, that you have the maximum of `attendDate`.

Comment: I think suggested query (with group + having) is extremely expensive and should not be used in this case. It would be a bottleneck when more rows added in the table.

Answer (score 0):

I would write this as an `EXISTS` query:

```
SELECT
   c.custRFID
FROM
   tbl_cust c
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM tbl_attend a
                  WHERE c.custRFID = a.RFID AND
                  MONTH(a.attendDate) = MONTH(CURDATE()) AND
                  YEAR(a.attendDate) = YEAR(CURDATE()));
```

Comment: Tim, thanks for the feedback, I will check the manual to read up on the **EXISTS** query options.  I will keep you informed on my progress is this works for me.

Comment: @WillD. If mark correct is possible that would be appreciated.

Comment: Tim, This gives me an error when I attempt to run the sql... I will keep checking my code.

Comment: I got this past the error, but it returns all 176 records in the table.  not sure this is going to work for what I need.  If a customer has been a member for 12 months then they will have 12 entries.  I only want to see the most current entry ONLY if it was not from this calendar month, i.e. November 1-20 of 2018.  I don't want to see every entry of those in past.  The goal here is so we can easliy identify who we need to call this month.

Comment: Add sample data to your question for best results.

Comment: I am still learning all of the ways to input questions here at Stackoverflow.  I added content to the original question, hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using LEFT JOIN.
Also, try not to use YEAR(column) & MONTH(column) functions in ON/WHERE clauses as SQL will not be able to use indeces in this case.
Something like this should do the trick:

```
SELECT
    c.custRFID,
    a.attendID,
    a.RFID,
    a.attendDate,
    a.attendStatus,
    a.attendStatusCode,
    a.attendNotes
FROM
    tbl_cust c
    LEFT JOIN tbl_attend a ON (
            c.custRFID = a.RFID
        AND a.attendDate > DATE_SUB(LAST_DAY(CURDATE()), INTERVAL 1 MONTH)
        AND a.attendDate <= LAST_DAY(CURDATE())
    )
WHERE
    a.RFID IS NULL
```

Comment: There will never be a Null entry in the RFID Column of any of the tables.  If the RFID tag is not scanned the record does not exist.

Comment: You should read about left join a bit more: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/join.html "If there is no matching row for the right table in the ON or USING part in a LEFT JOIN, a row with all columns set to NULL is used for the right table. You can use this fact to find rows in a table that have no counterpart in another table: "

Comment: Reading up on the joins... I will report back once I finish reading it.